# Exec systemctl after deployment by capistrano

Tags: ruby, http, nginx, capistrano

I want to restart `Nginx-unit` after deployment by `Capistrano`

```
namespace :deploy do
    desc 'Collec Static Files'
    task :collectImg do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute "sudo systemctl restart unit"
        end
    end
    after :publishing, :collectImg
end
```

After above code, there comes error log like this.

Is there any good way to use systemctl in deployment script???

```
DEBUG [08ce969a] Command: sudo systemctl restart unit

DEBUG [08ce969a]    sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

Answer (score 2):

First - Great you are using NGINX Unit with Capistrano!

This problem is related to a couple of issues at a time.

### 1. Enable tty mode

Add this to your deployment configuration `deploy.rb`. Capistrano 3.

```rb
set :pty, true
```

More Information about [PTY](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/ptys/)

### 2. Modify your sudoers file on the App Server

You have to allow the deployment user to execute sudo commands without the need of entering a password. You can / should limit this power to specific resources. I have added `restart` and `status` as examples.

```sh
deploy ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/systemctl restart unit.serivce, /bin/systemctl status unit.serivce
```

As a reference see [Capistrano Auth](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#toc_8)

Would like to chat about your capistrano configuration on our Community NGINX channel.